# RemoteControl on Samba AD?

Tags: ubuntu, samba, remote-desktop, remote-control, zentyal-linux

I have an AD/DC, running on Zentyal 6.1 (wich is a web service of Samba 4.11 running on 18 iirc). But here is the thing: I have some users (we are on the same network, I can even reach them via ping, those users use Win7 and Win10 as OS) far away from me (more than 300 km) and due to the pandemic situation in my country I can't go over there and do what I need to do myself. I have a virtual PC running Win7 with RSAT so I can easily manage users and the GPOs with Windows mmc. There is a tab called **Remote controller** wich intrigue me, I have done some research and it seems like an old tool wich right now it's not usable.

I know there are other tools as the RemoteControllerClient, Windows's RDP, VNCs servers and so on, but out of curiosity I would love to know if there is an integrated tool on AD/DC (running on **Samba!**) wich can be used in order to control (if not, at least to see the display) the session of a PC in my domain.

Greetings